# pgfplots option "skip coords between index" does not work with boxplot

Tags: pgfplots

The `skip` option in the following code works only for the scatter plot and does not work for boxplot nor hist.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
    \begin{axis}[ytick={0,0.5,1}, ymax=2, ymin=0, axis y line=left, axis x line=bottom,xmin = 0, xmax=
      8, small, boxplot/draw position=1.5, boxplot/box extend=.2, skip coords between index={0}{140}]

      \addplot+[mark size=0.5pt, boxplot]table[x index = 0, y index=\INDEX]{Graphics/iris.dat}

      \addplot [hist=density, fill=orange!75, draw=orange!50!black] table [x index = 0, y index=\INDEX]{Graphics/iris.dat};

      \addplot[scatter, only marks, mark=|, mark size=2pt, thick] table[x index=\INDEX ,y expr=0.02]{Graphics/iris.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first part is a partial answer, addressing only `hist`. See below for a possible workaround for `boxplot`. For reference, the `iris.dat` I used in all the following is structured like this:

```
$ head -n5 iris.dat 
sl sw pl pw
5.10 3.50 1.40 0.20
4.90 3.00 1.40 0.20
4.70 3.20 1.30 0.20
4.60 3.10 1.50 0.20
```

---

It is mentioned in a *Technical note* on page 390 of the manual for version 1.15 of `pgfplots`, under the description of `skip coords between index` that

> this style usually applies to *x* coordinates (i.e. it counts *x* coordinates). In case you
>   want to apply it to something like `hist/data` or `quiver/u`, you can
>
> 1. append an asterisk ‘*’ to the style’s name and
> 2. provide the target coordinate’s name as first argument.
>
> For example, `skip coords between index*={hist/data}{2}{4}` applies to `hist/data`.

Hence, if you add `skip coords between index*={hist/data}{0}{140}` to the `axis` options, the filtering seems to work for `hist`. I do not know what the equivalent for `boxplot` is, if there is one (`boxplot/data` instead of `hist/data` didn't work here at least).

[image: output of first code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\begin{axis}[
   ytick={0,0.5,1},
   ymax=2, ymin=0,
   axis y line=left,
   axis x line=bottom,
   xmin = 0, xmax=8,
   small,
   boxplot/draw position=1.5,
   boxplot/box extend=.2,
   skip coords between index*={hist/data}{0}{140},
   skip coords between index={0}{140}
]

\newcommand\INDEX{2}

  \addplot+[mark size=0.5pt,boxplot] table[x index = 0, y index=\INDEX]{iris.dat};

  \addplot [hist=density, fill=orange!75, draw=orange!50!black] table [x index = 0, y index=\INDEX]{iris.dat};

 \addplot[scatter, only marks, mark=|, mark size=2pt, thick] table[x index=\INDEX ,y expr=0.02]{iris.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Possible workaround for boxplot

This is rather more elaborate, but it does appear at first glance to give useful output.  What I do below is to define a macro `\nanrows{i}{j}` which makes a copy of the iris table, but replaces all values for row numbers between `i` and `j` with `nan`. In so doing a new column is also added, that contains the row number. This new table is saved as `\IRISnan`

The addition of a new column means that the column indexes used in `\addplot` has to be increased by 1.

(Very likely, there are more elegant ways of doing the same.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,longtable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableread{iris.dat}\IRIS
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\IRIS}
\newcommand\NUMROWS\pgfplotsretval

\newcommand\nancol[4]{%
% #1: column name
% #2: table name
% #3: start index for nans
% #4: end index for nans
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code={
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmp{#3-1} % only have ">" comparison, not ">=", so subtract 1
  \ifnum \thisrow{index}>\tmp
     \ifnum \thisrow{index}<#4
       \edef\entry{nan} % if "lower value" <= index < "upper value", set value to nan
     \else
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\thisrow{index}}{#1}\of\IRIS %otherwise use value from original iris-table
        \edef\entry{\pgfplotsretval}
      \fi
   \else
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\thisrow{index}}{#1}\of\IRIS
        \edef\entry{\pgfplotsretval}
   \fi
   \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
}
]{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\nanrows[3][\IRISnan]{
% #1: name of new table, optional
% #2: start index for nans, passed to \nancol
% #3: end index for nans, passed to \nancol
\pgfplotstablenew[
  columns={index},
  create on use/index/.style={create col/set list={0,...,\NUMROWS}}
]{\NUMROWS}{#1}
\nancol{sl}{#1}{#2}{#3}
\nancol{sw}{#1}{#2}{#3}
\nancol{pl}{#1}{#2}{#3}
\nancol{pw}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}

% set value in rows 0-99 to nan
% resulting table saved in \IRISnan
\nanrows{0}{140}

\begin{document}
% if you want to look at the table (requires longtable package, see preamble)
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[begin table=\begin{longtable},end table=\end{longtable}]\IRISnan
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\begin{axis}[
   ytick={0,0.5,1},
   ymax=2, ymin=0,
   axis y line=left,
   axis x line=bottom,
   xmin = 0, xmax=8,
   small,
   boxplot/draw position=1.5,
   boxplot/box extend=.2,
   filter discard warning=false % removes a lot of warnings about unbounded coordinates
]

\newcommand\INDEX{3}

  \addplot+[mark size=0.5pt,boxplot] table[x index = 1, y index=\INDEX]{\IRISnan};

  \addplot [hist=density, fill=orange!75, draw=orange!50!black] table [x index = 1, y index=\INDEX]{\IRISnan};

   \addplot[scatter, only marks, mark=|, mark size=2pt, thick] table[x index=\INDEX ,y expr=0.02]{\IRISnan};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much; you have done too much work. For histogram, I saw that line in the manual but I failed to use it as you have done. Regard the boxplot, yes I wish if there is direct option like the histogram one. Thanks

Comment: Any update on a more elegant way of solving the problem for boxplot?

Comment: @MDescamps Not from me, but then, I never said I'd try finding one either .. You could always ask new question, linking back to this answer, I suppose.

Comment: [Done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597369/178152)