# Ommiting a row when boxplotting

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, boxplot

I have a file that looks like this:

```
        1   0.237340    0.135170    0.339511    0.237653    0.135482    0.339823    
        2   0.561320    0.422007    0.700633    0.165871    0.026558    0.305184    
        3   0.694760    0.534205    0.855314    0.074856    -0.085698   0.235411    
        4   0.728306    0.560179    0.896432    0.003361    -0.164765   0.171487    
        5   0.711710    0.544944    0.878477    -0.044582   -0.211349   0.122184    
        6   0.671241    0.511191    0.831291    -0.073347   -0.233397   0.086703    
        7   0.621177    0.471219    0.771135    -0.088418   -0.238376   0.061540    
        8   0.569354    0.431826    0.706882    -0.094382   -0.231910   0.043146    
        9   0.519973    0.396571    0.643376    -0.094619   -0.218022   0.028783    
        10  0.475121    0.366990    0.583251    -0.091467   -0.199598   0.016664
```

Most of the time, I need to plot two columns against eachother. That works fine. Occasionally, however, I need a row-wise boxplot. To do this, my idea was to transpose the table and then select the row I want as a column. The problem then is that the first row contains the indices and needs to be removed. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404861/178152) shows how to ommit a number of rows for scatter plots and histrograms, but the suggested workaround for boxplots is a bit hacky. I was wondering if there is an easyier solution, especially since I only need to ommit the first row and also know its value.

This is what I have now, but since the index is not ommited, there is a big outlier (10) in the boxplot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        1   0.237340    0.135170    0.339511    0.237653    0.135482    0.339823    
        2   0.561320    0.422007    0.700633    0.165871    0.026558    0.305184    
        3   0.694760    0.534205    0.855314    0.074856    -0.085698   0.235411    
        4   0.728306    0.560179    0.896432    0.003361    -0.164765   0.171487    
        5   0.711710    0.544944    0.878477    -0.044582   -0.211349   0.122184    
        6   0.671241    0.511191    0.831291    -0.073347   -0.233397   0.086703    
        7   0.621177    0.471219    0.771135    -0.088418   -0.238376   0.061540    
        8   0.569354    0.431826    0.706882    -0.094382   -0.231910   0.043146    
        9   0.519973    0.396571    0.643376    -0.094619   -0.218022   0.028783    
        10  0.475121    0.366990    0.583251    -0.091467   -0.199598   0.016664    
    }{\table}
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[string type]\tableT{\table}
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\tableT}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\numberofCols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot+[boxplot] table [y index=\numberofCols]{\tableT};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can tell `pgfplotstable` to use the first column as the header row for the transposed table, with `colnames from={0}`. Because your table doesn't have a header row, no text entries in the first row, column indices are used as column names. `pgfplotstable` counts from zero, so `0` is the first column.

Note by the way that with `pgfplotstableread{..}\table` you break the `table` environment, because `\begin{table}` does `\table`, so be careful what you use for table names.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % loads pgfplots which loads tikz
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}


\begin{document}

    % be careful what you name these, with \table you break the table-environment,
    % because \begin{table} does \table "behind the scenes"
    \pgfplotstableread{
        1   0.237340    0.135170    0.339511    0.237653    0.135482    0.339823    
        2   0.561320    0.422007    0.700633    0.165871    0.026558    0.305184    
        3   0.694760    0.534205    0.855314    0.074856    -0.085698   0.235411    
        4   0.728306    0.560179    0.896432    0.003361    -0.164765   0.171487    
        5   0.711710    0.544944    0.878477    -0.044582   -0.211349   0.122184    
        6   0.671241    0.511191    0.831291    -0.073347   -0.233397   0.086703    
        7   0.621177    0.471219    0.771135    -0.088418   -0.238376   0.061540    
        8   0.569354    0.431826    0.706882    -0.094382   -0.231910   0.043146    
        9   0.519973    0.396571    0.643376    -0.094619   -0.218022   0.028783    
        10  0.475121    0.366990    0.583251    -0.091467   -0.199598   0.016664    
    }{\datatable}

    % the colnames from-key lets you define a column from the old table
    % to use as column names in the transposed one
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[string type,colnames from={0}]\tableT{\datatable}
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\tableT}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\numberofCols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    
    \pgfplotstabletypeset\tableT
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot+[boxplot] table [y index=\numberofCols]{\tableT};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```